# awk - remove new line after printing all columns

Tags: awk, newline

i am running a following awk script

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS="|" ; OFS="|" };  { printf $0, $1 "_" $2  }' .someFile
```

unfortunatley the concatention of fields 1 and 2 is printed on new line, looks like the last field contains a new line character

how can i trim it ?

Comment: Please read [ask] and do as it suggests.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `printf` (which may have been accidental), I think you can use this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" } { printf "%s%s%s_%s", $0, OFS, $1, $2 }' .someFile
```

`printf` should always be used with a format string. `printf` doesn't add the Output Record Separator to the end of what it prints, so you have to do that yourself using `\n` in the format string or by adding `%s` and passing `ORS` as the last argument to `printf`.

In this case, I think you can just use `print` though:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|" } { print $0, $1 "_" $2 }' .someFile
```